# cucumber throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/FeatureParser

Tags: java, junit, jar, cucumber

I'm learning Cucumber and I'm getting the FeatureParser error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/FeatureParser
```

I have imported below jar files

1. gherkin-9.2.0.jar
2. cucumber-core-5.2.0.jar
3. cucumber-java-5.2.0.jar
4. cucumber-junit-5.2.0.jar
5. cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
6. cucumber-plugin-5.2.0.jar

i have written code like below

LoginTestRunner.java

```
package cucumberTests;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;



@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="features", glue="stepImplementations")
public class LoginTestRunner {

}
```

I have written feature file as well.

Getting below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/FeatureParser
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:35)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.lambda$new$0(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:39)
    at java.base/java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$processResource$2(ResourceScanner.java:126)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:67)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:52)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2724)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:26)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:109)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:86)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:156)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:113)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolveTestClass(ClassSelectorResolver.java:66)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1631)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:174)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:112)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.<init>(JUnit5TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParser
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Seems like it's part of cucumber-jvm: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/gherkin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/gherkin/FeatureParser.java

Comment: Make sure #3 is on your classpath: `cucumber-java-5.2.0.jar`

Comment: `5.2.0` was only released recently -- I'd use `5.1.3` as recommended by their site as it's probably more stable

Comment: Thank you. I'm still facing the same issue, post updating the jar files.

Comment: Try to run the tests without cucumber-jvm-deps jar

Answer (score 4):

> I'm learning Cucumber and I'm getting the FeatureParser error

If you follow the [10 minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) you'll get an introduction that uses Maven dependency management.

In addition to this tutorial I would strongly urge you to invest time in learning either Maven or Gradle along with Cucumber. Amongst other things these tools will automate your dependency management and this can make your life much easier.

For example:

If you want to use Cucumber with JUnit 4 and annotation based step definitions you would declare this minimal set of dependencies in a Maven `pom.xml` file.

```
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>5.2.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

By telling Maven what your dependencies are Maven can calculate your transitive dependencies i.e: the dependencies of your dependencies.

This has many advantages. One example would be using the `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` command to will list all dependencies. This is much faster and much less error prone then downloading jar files by hand and hoping that you have the right ones.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton >-------------------
[INFO] Building Cucumber-Java Skeleton 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cucumber-java-skeleton ---
[INFO] cucumber:cucumber-java-skeleton:jar:0.0.1
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-java:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin-vintage:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:tag-expressions:jar:2.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:jar:8.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:datatable:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-plugin:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.cucumber:docstring:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:jar:5.2.0:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.781 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-10T23:00:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency and rebuild your project:

Note that the scope is set to test --

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when the class is found at compile time, but not at runtime. So you need to ensure this .jar is available at runtime

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you're using Eclipse, make sure that you have the project class path set to include the dependency and that it's built and embedded into the project

Comment: thanks for the reply I'm not using maven pom file I've imported the jar into my project. I have added these dependency jar, cucumber-java-5.2.0.jar, cucumber-java8-5.2.0.jar. still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In your testrunner.java file , try giving full path of feature file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).