# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:Class cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions not implement requested interface io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOptions

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, appium

I am trying to run cucumber with testNG for my appium mobile automation testing. But getting below error while running the Testrunner through TestNG. I tried to check all the availble version of the cucumber.io but couldnt get anything wooking.. Can anyone please suggest what could be the issue here?

or what version of cucumber will solve this proble?

I am using this pom:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.1</serenity.cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Cucumber-JVM -->

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Cucumber Testng Report , cucumber.api.testng.TestNgReporter -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--cucumber.api.java.en.And, Given , When, Then -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.5</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Extent report -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Cucumber report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

TestNG file :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
<!--    <parameter name="config" value="DEVINT2" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="web" />
    <parameter name="mobileOS" value="andriod" /> -->
    <test name="Test" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.calculator.testrunner.TestRunner_ST" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestRunner:

```
import com.calculator.cucumber.AbtractBaseTestNGCucumber;
import com.calculator.helperapis.Configuration;
import com.calculator.utils.ReportGenerator;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;


@CucumberOptions(snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        glue = {
                "com.calculator.stepdefinations" }, 
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                        "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt",
                        "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"},
        monochrome = true, 
        dryRun = true,
        //tags = { "@CalcTask"}, 
        features = {
        "src/main/resources/FeatureFiles/Calculator_Test.feature",


        })

public class TestRunner_ST extends AbtractBaseTestNGCucumber {
}
```

Getting Exception as :

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions does not implement the requested interface io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOptions
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:64)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:37)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:54)
    at com.calculator.cucumber.AbtractBaseTestNGCucumber.setUpClass(AbtractBaseTestNGCucumber.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cucumber throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/FeatureParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158172/cucumber-throwing-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-io-cucumber-core-gherkin-featu)

Comment: You have to look at your dependencies. They're not compatible with each other.