# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng, bdd

I am trying to run cucumber with Java and TestNG. But I am getting an exception where it says: `cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z`

The following is my TestRunner class, pom.xml and testng.xml.

This is my TestRunner.java class:

```
package MyRunner;

import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/cucumber-report.html","usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"
        },
        features = "src/test/resources/Features",
        glue = {"src/test/java/StepDef",
        }
//        tags = {"~@Ignore"}
)
public class TestRunner {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gif-mfc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gif-mfc-alert-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.15.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>gif-mfc-alert</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>7.0.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walmart.ecommerce.fulfillment.restclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-client-resttemplate</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walmart.ecommerce.fulfillment.schema</groupId>
            <artifactId>fulfillment-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1908.288</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walmart.ecommerce.fulfillment</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmanager-2-0</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.walmart.ecommerce.fulfillment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fulfillment-commons-dao</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.walmart.ecommerce.fulfillment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fulfillment-common-config-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central2</id>
            <url>http://gec-maven-nexus.walmart.com/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>pangaea_releases</id>
            <url>http://gec-maven-nexus.walmart.com/nexus/content/repositories/pangaea_releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>pangaea_snapshots</id>
            <url>http://gec-maven-nexus.walmart.com/nexus/content/repositories/pangaea_snapshots</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

My testng.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests"
       thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
<test name="MFC Alert Test cases" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="MyRunner.TestRunner" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:213)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:61)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addPlugins(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:96)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:57)
    at MyRunner.TestRunner.setUpClass(TestRunner.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyRunner.TestRunner.scenarios(TestRunner.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I updated all the maven dependencies. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: you mess up cucumbers of different versions

Comment: @AlexeyR. is there any document where I will the synchronized versions?

Comment: All I can say is that you need to have a careful look at your dependencies. It will be easier to start from scratch and make your problem smaller first.

Comment: To start from scratch, have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: And this also applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158172/cucumber-throwing-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-io-cucumber-core-gherkin-featu/60159391#60159391