# java.util.Optional io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParser.parse error

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm

I'm facing this issue with cucumber 7.11.1

When I run tests I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Optional io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParser.parse(java.net.URI, java.io.InputStream, java.util.function.Supplier)'
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$processResource$1(ResourceScanner.java:79)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:60)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2812)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:31)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:61)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$findResourcesForUris$3(ResourceScanner.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUris(ResourceScanner.java:107)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForClasspathResource(ResourceScanner.java:115)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:131)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:80)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

There is an issue with getting features.

I'm using cucumber 7.11.1 / maven surefire 3.0.0-M7 / maven compiler plugin 3.10.1. I want to launch tests through a maven cmd.

Comment: Sounds like you messed up your dependencies. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158172/cucumber-throwing-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-io-cucumber-core-gherkin-featu/60159391#60159391

Answer (score 1):

to resolve this problem you need to add dependency
`<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId> <version>7.x.x</version>**strong text**`